# PHP Zip Maximum Number of Files

Tags: php, zip

I have a little Problem. I have a Script, that allows people to upload files in a multiple select input. Those input fields are submitted via HTTPXML Request. But i tried to select 98 Pictures with about 900MB - They were uploaded and the ZIP Script finished without any error. But when I want to download the File it is only 200 MB and only 20 Pictures are in the ZIP. I increased the maximum execution time on the server - but the script seems to run for 24 seconds only. I increased the PHP Memory Limit to 2 GB - The Server has enough Ram as well. The Maximum File Size is about 2GB the Maximum Upload Size too.

Here The Script:

```html
$zip = new ZipArchive();
 $res = $zip->open(__DIR__."/../files/".$filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
 if($res){
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['datei']['name']); $i++){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'][$i], __DIR__.'/../temp/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'][$i]);
   if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/../temp/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'][$i]) && is_readable(__DIR__.'/../temp/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'][$i])){
    $zip->addFile(__DIR__.'/../temp/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'][$i], $_FILES['datei']['name'][$i]);
   }else{
    $status['uploaded_file'] = 500;
   }
  }
  $res_close = $zip->close(); 
  if($res_close){
   $status['uploaded_file'] = 200;
  }
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['datei']['name']); $i++){
   unlink(__DIR__.'/../temp/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'][$i]);
  }
 }else{
  die($res);
  $status['uploaded_file'] = 500;
 }
```

The Script basically moves all the TEMP Files to another TEMP Folder. From Those TEMP Folder they are being Zipped to a file folder. Afterwords the Files from the TEMP Folder are going to be deleted.

Is there anything stupid I am doing wrong? Or is there another limitation I didnt see?

Thanks for Help

Comment: I tested uploading a single File with 900MB - it took about 1-2 Minutes to process, but it worked fine...

Comment: Even if i upload 21 files - it is still processing 20 Files only...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads